# best syntax to set a global boolean variable in a loop in a function in javascript

Tags: javascript

So this is what I have right now:

```
            var flag = false;

            (function() {
                for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
                    // some code ....
                    // How can I rewrite the following?
                    if (!flag) {
                        flag = true;
                        // can't break
                    }
                }
            })();

            console.log(flag);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btc6wjw9/

My goal is set the flag to true when the function executes.  What is the more elegant syntax with the same or better performance?

Thanks!

Update:
I have since learned that changing a boolean value is faster than checking it:
http://jsfiddle.net/xq7n7bry/

Comment: Interesting question, let's see the feedback on flipping the switch. It'll be more about elegance than performance, I assume. By the way, `i++` is one character less at least.

Comment: And you don't really need the brackets after the `if` statement in this case...

Comment: I think you have dismissed too much of the code with comments for the purpose of the function to be apparent. If your goal is to set the flag to be true based on some condition in the loop then there is no need for `if (!flag) flag = true;`, just write `flag = true;` instead

Comment: What's the point of `flag`? Is there some code in the loop that should only happen on the first iteration?

Comment: Please provide the full code, and elaborate your goal. Currently, you whole script could be reduced to `console.log(true)`

Comment: I am only trying to see if there is a javascript syntax to make this better.  If there is none, that's fine.  Thanks for checking.

Comment: As Bergi mentioned, deleting all of the posted code and adding `console.log(true)` is better as far as we can tell because there is nothing else to go by with the code you posted

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  Please ignore the console.log.  I am really asking how to write something better than if (!flag) {flag = true;}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        var flag = false;

        (function() {
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i += 1) {
                // some code ....
            }
            flag = true;
        })();

        console.log(flag);
```

I don't really understand the point of your question, but if you want to set it to true when the function is called, just set it to true when the function is called.

Comment: Maybe we can ignore the loop.  I guess I am asking if there is a better way of writing:                   if (!flag) {flag = true;}.  There might be other functions setting it to true.

Comment: Your requirement was setting flag = true if the function was called. Why does it matter if other functions also set it to true? That's as easy and clean as you can do it.

Comment: Right, but I don't want to reset the true flag to true every time the function is call, hence the check for if (!flag), doesn't that help performance?

Comment: @techguy2000 "My goal is set the flag to true when the function executes." Is what you said. That's what my answer gave you.

Comment: @techguy2000, no it does not help performance, checking a conditional requires computation time

Answer (score -1):

One way to rewrite:

```
if (!flag) {flag = true;}
```

is

```
flag = (!flag ? true: flag );
```

This is not necessarily better, as an assignment will be made at each iteration.

Comment: There is no advantage here, might as well just write `flag = true;`

Comment: @asimes that's what I said... `This is not necessarily better, as an assignment will be made at each iteration`   I was merely showing another way to rewrite an if statement... really a down vote????

Comment: Yes, a down vote. You took his code that is inefficient and wrote it in an equally inefficient way. He asked how to make it better, that doesn't do what he asked

Comment: Did I assert it was better?

Comment: Why is if (!flag) {flag = true;} inefficient?